# Create Akka actor in another actor

Tags: scala, akka

I create an actor A. When I send a message to A, the `receive` method tries to create an actor B. When I run a piece of code that calls:

```
context.system.actorOf(Props[B], "B")
```

I get an exception:

```
InvalidActorNameException: actor name [B] is not unique!
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Actor paths](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/addressing.html#what-is-an-actor-path-) (part of which is the name that you pass to `system.actorOf` or `context.actorOf`, if you use the variants of `actorOf` that take a name) must be unique in an actor system. You're probably sending more than one message to actor A: every time actor A receives this message, it tries to create a top-level actor B with the name "B". Either drop the name altogether...

```
context.system.actorOf(Props[B])
```

...or add a unique identifier to the name. For example:

```
val uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
context.system.actorOf(Props[B], s"B-${uuid}")
```

---

As a side note, top-level actors (i.e., actors created via `system.actorOf`) should be made sparingly, as the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/actor-systems.html#actor-best-practices) advises:

> Top-level actors are the innermost part of your Error Kernel, so create them sparingly and prefer truly hierarchical systems. This has benefits with respect to fault-handling (both considering the granularity of configuration and the performance) and it also reduces the strain on the guardian actor, which is a single point of contention if over-used.

If your intent is to create an actor B as a child of actor A every time the latter receives a message, then use `context.actorOf`.